# How to print fibonacci series and its reverse in a single loop in c or java?

Tags: java, c, fibonacci

the output should look something like this:

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13..

..13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0

I thought of using two arrays in java and then using Arrays.tostring() on those two arrays to print both values,but still I couldn't solve it in one loop.
Apart from that I tries doing it in this way

```
int main()
{
   int n,j,c;
   int a=0,b=1;
   printf("enter total no of terms:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   int arr[n];
   arr[0]=a;
   arr[1]=b;

   printf("%d\t %d\t",arr[0],arr[1]);

    for(j=2;j<=((2*n)-1);j++)
    {  
       if(j<=n-1)
       {
          c=a+b;
          arr[j]=c;
          printf("%d\t",arr[j]);
          a=b;
          b=c;
          if(j==n-1)
           printf("\n");

       }
       else
       {  
           arr[j]=b;
           printf("%d\t",arr[j]);
           c=a;
           a=b-a;
           b=c;
       }


    }  

  getch();
}
```

This solves my problem but is there any shorter and more efficient method to this question?

Comment: *sniff* that smells like homework

Comment: fibonacci up to what number?

Comment: This has a pretty trivial solution if done recursively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with 3 variables with the values 0, 1 (`int num1 = 0;` and int `int num2 = 1;`) and undefined (`int num3;`). Print 1 and 2.
If you want up to 13 and back, do a loop of 12 times.
Inside the loop, check if the loop has been done 6 times (if index starts at 0, index<6). If yes, insert to num3 the value of num1+num2. If not, insert to num3 the value of 
After that, print num3 and move num2 to num1 and num3 to num2 (`num1=num2; num2=num3;`)